# Linearise Nonlinear ODE Square Derivative Term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to linearise an ODE of the form:
$${\Bigr(\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigr)}^2 - A\frac{dy}{dx}-By^2=C$$

What substitution could turn this into a traditional nonlinear ODE (e.g. Ricatti Equation or Separable) or a sensible Linear ODE?